# WiFi networks not showing in elementary OS loki

Tags: release-loki, wifi, drivers

i just installed elementary os and dual booted it with my windows 10 OS. but after everything my wifi does not see networks whereas these networks show full bars in my windows os. it only shows a signle bar of wifi from my phone hotspot when my phone is right next to my pc. and disconnects often. my pc is HP 250 G4 and i have both UEFI mode and secure boot enabled. althogh i have typed all the terminal commands ive found online. still no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Ethernet cable you should connect it and update your machine before continuing:

`sudo apt update && sudo upgrade -y`

Run modprobe on the wireless adapter

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be`

Then try one of the following to see if it works:

`sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1` or `sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2`

This is a temporary solution. To make it permanent, once you figure out which antenna works for your machine try the following (where `X` is the antenna that works for your laptop):

`echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=X fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`